# Angular 2 http duplicated data

Tags: angular, api, request

I finally made correctly http request for my application.
For my own purpose, i divided my call on service. 
My data is just duplicated every single construct of my component.
[image: image of duplicated data problem]

As you can see on screenshot.

How can i optimize my request?

```
export class FriendsComponent implements OnInit {
data: any;

  constructor(dataService: DataService) {
    for (let i of dataService.friends) {
      dataService.query = `${dataService.apiUrl}${i.nick}${dataService.apikey}`;

      dataService.getContacts();

    }

this.data  = dataService.data;
console.log(this.data);
  }



 ngOnInit() {

 }

}
```

DataService

```
@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  friends = FRIEND;
  apikey = APIKEY;
  nick: string[];
  query: string;

  public apiUrl =
    'https://eun1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/';
  data: Array<any> = [];
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getFriendData(query) {

    return this.http.get(query)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());

  }
  getContacts() {
    this.getFriendData(this.query).subscribe(data => {
      this.data.push(data);
    });
  }
}
```

In app.module.ts, in section "providers" i have my "DataService" service.

Comment: post your code here!

Comment: You know how to [ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here?

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: @Sajeetharan and rest of people. I`m sorry, i forgot to send my code.

Comment: what you are trying to archive, should be solved by using rxjs store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing to the same array inside the service, instead do it inside the component

```
 data: any;
 constructor(dataService: DataService) {    
      dataService.query = `${dataService.apiUrl}${i.nick}${dataService.apikey}`;
      this.dataService.getFriendData(this.query).subscribe(data => {
           this.data = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok. This is solution for duplicate data problem.Thank you. However, my goal of this question was how to make one request for whole lifecycle of user visit.

Comment: for that you need to make an api to accept multiple ids and return the matching results